# Disabling WP bit in CR0 Register in 64 bit Mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, virtual-memory, osdev

What I'm trying to do here is write to read-only kernel mode code belonging to the address space of ntoskrnl.exe but my machine keeps locking up and everything freezes which requires a reboot. Thanks to the book Rootkit Arsenal I'm using the same code that they have provided to disable the WP bit and then enable the WP bit. However with a single exception the code in the book is written for 32 bit CPU's . So here is my attempt to modify it in order to make compatible for 64 bit CPU's. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community and the code is targeting Windows 8.1 Pro (64 bit) at the moment. I've written two assembly procedures as seen here below.

Can someone tell me if the code is correct and if not please do share what the code should look like for 64 bit architecture.

```
DisableWP PROC PUBLIC

CLI
PUSH RBX
MOV RBX, CR0
AND RBX, 0FFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFh
MOV CR0, RBX
POP RBX
RET

DisableWP ENDP

EnableWP PROC PUBLIC

PUSH RBX
MOV RBX, CR0
OR RBX, 0000000000010000h
MOV CR0, RBX
POP RBX
STI
RET

EnableWP ENDP
```

Comment: I'd guess that the code worked. Note that WP is needed so that if kernel writes to a "copy on write" page it triggers the copying and doesn't corrupt the original; and with WP disabled this doesn't happen and kernel just corrupts all kinds of data (causing the machine to lock up as everything freezes).

Comment: Do you call EnableWP right away after calling DisableWP?  If not, you're leaving interrupts disabled (by `cli`), which will lock up that CPU if you just let it go to sleep. That can lock up the whole system, since kernels often need to make sure something's happened on all core.  (And by "right away", I mean from the same block of code that called DisableWP, not something that needs a timer interrupt to get scheduled, but you disabled interrupts.  Because as @Brendan points out, letting the scheduler run any other process could be fatal with the WP bit disabled, breaking virtual memory.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I would call DisableWP() then modify the address space of ntoskrnl.exe then call EnableWP() all in the same block of code. My code was still freezing up without the CLI/STI instructions. I think I understand what you and Brendan are saying. There are no kernel mode sleep equivalent functions that I'm using between the DisableWP() and EnableWP() functions. It's all in the same block of code.

Comment: You probably should keep the CLI/STI, that will make sure an interrupt doesn't let the kernel schedule a different task while WP is still disabled on this core.  Maybe whatever modification you make to ntoskrnl.exe's address space is the problem; have you tried *just* disable / enable back to back without doing anything in between?  Or with some dummy delay to see if timing is somehow relevant, like a loop that runs `pause` 20 to 100 times.

Comment: @PeterCordes just  tested the scenario that you asked about DisableWP() and EnableWP() back to back with no code in between. It works no freezing or lock up.